# Regex for this URL, http://www.chip.de and this domain chip.de

Tags: regex, url, regular-language

I am trying to create a regex to look for similar URL and domain like this below

```
*chip.de
http://www.chip.de*
```

I tried to use the regex expression

```
http?:\/\/([\w\.-]+)([\/\w \.-]*)
```

It did not capture the URL.

I tried to use the url, https://www.regextester.com/99497 to test it out and it failed..

What am I missing?

Please create two rules for domain and URL

Thank you

Comment: To clarify, should the regex only match URLs which contain `chip.de`?

Comment: The regex has nothing specific for `chip.de`. Can you update the question with examples that should and should not match, and if possible add a tag for the the tool or language.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply looking for regex that will match URLs which include `chip.de` then please try this and let me know if it is sufficient:

```
https?\:\/\/www\.chip\.de.*
```

Comment: If need be, I've also worked out something that may be useful : `\b((http|https):\/\/)?(www\.)?chip\.de\b`